# How can I keybind a custom voice note to a particular set of keys?

Tags: shortcut-keys

I want to bind a custom voice note with a particular set of keys, I did some research but most of the answers are about how to keybind an operation. I wanna know is it possible to keybind custom voice note to a particular set of keys?

Comment: You indeed need to know your operation before you can bind it to a keyboard. I assume the voice note is an audio file? The command `aplay`, installed by default, can play an audio file.

Comment: what I want to do is, press a combination of keys(say ctr+backspace+x) and then a sound should play, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a command line option to play the sound file, and then bind that command to a shortcut key. One option is to use `ffplay`, part of `ffmpeg` and installed by default. Thus, a command like

```
ffplay "/home/user/Music/"Custom voice.ogg"
```

will play the audio file "Custom voice.ogg". A window will appear. Closing the window will stop the playback.

If you do not want the window to appear, you can use the `-nodisp` option, as in

```
ffplay -nodisp "/home/user/Music/"Custom voice.ogg"
```

That way, you will not have an immediate way to stop, but you could define another hotkey that shuts ffplay down with the following command:

```
killall ffplay
```

This sends a SIGTERM signal to the program, i.e., requests the ffplay process to terminate.